# Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined even tho property has been defined

Tags: reactjs

So I came across this code and  wanted to combine it with a table that I created. I coped and pasted it to break apart and understand it. But I keep running into this issue, "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined". I'm still new to react, but I have done this type of thing many of time and I just stomped to why this happening

code:

```
const TableDnD = (superclass) => class extends superclass {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = this.state || {};
    this.state.columnX = 0;
    this.state.columnY = 0;
    this.state.dragging = false;
}

dragHandle(children) {
    return (
      <span onMouseDown={this._onStartDrag.bind(this)}>
        {children}
      </span>
    )
}

dragContainer(children) {
    const dragColumn = this.state.dragging ? this._renderDragColumn() : null;
    const styles = {
    position: "relative"
    };
    return (
      <div
        onMouseUp={this._endDrag.bind(this)}
        onMouseMove={this._updateStyles.bind(this)}
        onMouseOver={this._isOver.bind(this)}
        onMouseLeave={this._exitWithoutChange.bind(this)}
        style={styles}
        ref={(container) => this.container = container}
      >
        {children}
        {dragColumn}
      </div>
    )
}

   // Bunch of code for drag and drop table
}

class Table extends TableDnD(Component) {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        headers: this.props.headers, // right here the error haapens
        data: this.props.data,
    }
}

// other code
// render the component
render() {
   const headers = this.renderHeaders();
   const data = this.renderRows();
   // And finally, the table must be wrapped in the dragContainer method. That's it!
   return this.dragContainer(
       <table className="table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   {headers}
               </tr>
           </thead>
       <tbody>
          {data}
       </tbody>
    </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Table
```

Right at 'headers: this.props.headers' and same with data. The error: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined.

Even I declared the header property.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot access this.props in the constructor. Hence why props are passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `props.headers`, not `this.props.headers`.

Same thing will happen on the next line with `data`